# How to cast base class in to sub class in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, nsobject

In my Xamarin.iOS `ApiDefinition.cs`, I have following interfaces

```
// @protocol LSMAHandler <NSObject>
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]
interface LSMAHandler

 // @protocol LSMAHandlerRegister <LSMAHandler>
[BaseType(typeof(LSMAHandler))]
[Model]
interface LSMAHandlerRegister 

// @protocol LSMAHandlerPincode <LSMAHandler>
[BaseType(typeof(LSMAHandler))]
[Model]
interface LSMAHandlerPincode
```

Inside my another interface, I have a property like this.

```
[Export("agentHandler")]
NSObject AgentHandler { get; }
```

Ok that is my binding project. Now, inside my actual project I want to cast this `NSObject` into `LSMAHandler`. So I did something like this.

```
 NSObject handler = lSUniversal.AgentHandler;
 LSMAHandler myHandler = (LSMAHandler)handler;
```

But this above last line gives me an exception

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: The data that you have in `AgentHandler` is it of the type `LSMAHandler`? I don't think so

Comment: @G.hakim "@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSObject<LSMAHandler,LSMAHandlerPincode,LSMAHandlerRegister> *  agentHandler;" This is my objective c property. I want to define this in my ApiDefinition.cs